# HTML and CSS, selective text

Tags: html, css

How can I make every selected string instance written differently from others?

```
    <table><tr>
    <td> word1 word2 word3 .... abc ... abc ... abc   ... word N ... abc</td>
    </tr></table>
```

such as making them uppercase

```
     word1 word2 ... ABC ... ABC .... ABC ... wordN ... ABC
```

with pure HTML/CSS? No jscript, no jquery.

Something like

```
     <td stringInstance="abc" differBy="upper case"> .... </td>
```

Comment: Not possible with just HTML CSS

Comment: How about just wrap the ones you want changed in a `<span>` and apply styles to that `<span>`?

Comment: But the text is too long and there can be many instances and the text can be updated from time to time.

Comment: I still agree with @PaulRedmond that this would be the only way to accomplish this without JS.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you would have to update all the stuff you want changed but that is the only way to do it without js. You would basically show/hide the span when the parent is hovered

Comment: Your last resort, other than @PaulRedmond suggested, is to do it server side, using ASP/PHP

Comment: Are you able to use ASP/PHP?

Comment: @PellePenna Not yet. But will learn that too when time comes. Im not running without crawling first.

Comment: The quicker you start the faster you will see, how much you can do with that.

Comment: Just for science, @PaulRedmond solution could look like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpqUD/1/) . The key is `text-transform` attribute from CSS.

Comment: Then I simple "find and replace" with spans for those using f3 key?